# Помогите понять задание

Tags: sql, база-данных

Дело в том, что я не совсем понимаю что от меня требуют. Объясните пожалуйста, простыми словами, что именно я должен сделать?

> - Базы данных должны быть выверены на уровне отношений;
> - Из всех таблиц баз данных удалены свободные кортежи;
> - Отдельно предоставить лог-файл тестирования ID- объектов баз данных   (в случае выявления испорченных ID произвести "ремонт" сущностей)

Comment: Что конкретно из 4х пунктов вам не понятно?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Здравствуйте, вот есть задание, но я точно не уверен что я должен сделать. Хотелось бы описание каждого пункта более детально

Comment: **Все манипуляции с данными должны логироваться!!!**
Вот эта часть понятна? если нет - советую дальше не заниматься ничем связанным с базами, да и вообще компьютерами... Если эта часть понятна - **уточните что именно вам непонятно**

Comment: @Владимирклыков Что подразумевается под "свободный кортеж", "тестированием ID обьектов баз данных"?

Comment: Вот уже лучше, свободный - не участвующий в связи. т.е. если на запись не ссылается никто, и запись ни на кого не ссылается - она свободна...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо, это мне понятно, а тестирование?

Comment: Смотрите в ответе. почитайте хотябы статью на вики о реляционных БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Базы данных должны быть выверены на уровне отношений;
```

Это означает что все записи в БД должны быть связаны между собой, к примеру у вас есть таблица пользователей, и есть таблица прав пользователей, в таком случае у вас должны быть выставлены венро ключи между данными таблицами.

```
Из всех таблиц баз данных удалены свободные кортежи;
```

Все записи которые не участвуют в "связях" должны быть удалены из БД, т.е. не допускается существование записи как отдельной сущности.

```
Тестирование ID- объектов баз данных (в случае выявления испорченных ID произвести "ремонт" сущностей)
```

Вы должны позаботится о том чтобы записи с испорченными связями не существовали в БД, т.е. организовать проверку этих самых связей.(в первоначальном варианте пункт звучал не так, зря вы его модифицировали ибо изменился смысл сообщения)

П.с. последний пункт как он звучал изначально - вы должны организовать тестирование всех связей в БД, и в случае порчи связи попытаться ее восстановить, так же занести изменения в лог, если исправление невозможно - запись должна быть удалена, и это событие так же занесено в лог.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, я все понял. А что значит "произвести ремонт"? Как я могу ее "отремонтировать", если связь потеряна?

Comment: если вы ведете логи, то при анализе логов вы можете заметить что кто то изменил у дочерней записи ID или наоборот у родительской записи ID, и в логе это записано, а значит можно исправить вернув наместо верный ID

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, изменение на ID которого не существует? Логи я не веду, значит ничего не смогу сделать?

Comment: У вас в задании был пункт что все действия с данными должны логироваться. но если таки лог не ведется - то данные можно только удалить, что и будет исправлением.

Comment: Исчерпывающе, все понял. Спасибо!